# Java Store and compare huge key value pair maps on disk

Tags: java, key-value, key-value-store

I have a scenario in which i have to compare 2 Maps. I have to take a keys of the source Map and iterate through the target Map for the key for equals and then compare their values. The problems is that these Maps are supposed to hold very  high(>=10,000,000) volume of records. So i cannot keep these maps in-memory.

**Possible solutions:**

Storing both as text files as "key=value"

**Problems:**

We have to iterate through the target Map text file for every key value in the source which is ineffective and time consuming.

**Possible solutions:**
Storing both as text files as "key=value" and creating an index of id=>line number for target

**Problems:**

No effective method to directly read a line based on the line number from a big text file. Some methods use api's for Java 1.8 and they again need the file to be loaded in-memory

**Possible solutions:**

Storing both in a database

**Problems:**

In this case, we have to query the databases for every single key value. If we have 1 million keys in source and target, We have to query 1 million times. Ineffective and time consuming

**Possible solutions:**

Using [mapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/)

**Problems:**

Tried this, but it failed after 260,000 records. It gave an Writer thread failed exception mainly because i was using a 32bit JVM. So i want to write the implementation myself rather than relying on MapDB.

How do i effectively store/retrieve and compare the key value maps so that it wont hit the performance much when i am doing the comparison. At any time i cannot bring any thing in-memory because it will give Out of Memory exception. The solution should read and writes to the disk, not in-memory - I don't have 12 GB of RAM. Also the solution should work for 32/64 bit systems

Comment: I fail to see why you would have to query the database one million times. What result do you expect from comparing the values?

Comment: Have you researched other key-value stores for Java? There seem to be quite a few of them out there, and writing your own will take quite some time. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Robby After we store the maps in database, for every key in source map, we have to query target like select value from target where key='sourceKey' in order to compare(equals to give a boolean true/false value) the source and target value for the matched key.  I assume We cannot do a join also as it is going to take a huge amount of time to join these huge tables.

Comment: @Jim Looking into it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reasonably simple option:

- Put the maps on disk
- Sort them (in any of a number of ways)
- Open a reader for each map, and read the first line
- Iterate over the lines of each map, deciding which map to read from based on a comparison of "current" keys.

That way you only need two key/value pairs in memory at any one time.

For example, suppose we have a "source" map with keys A, B, H, I and a "target" map with keys B, C, I, J. The process would look like this:

- Read source=A, target=B
- Compare: source before target, so read another line from source (B)
- Compare: source and target keys are equal, so process the entry for B, and read another line from each (source=H, target=C)
- Compare: target before source, so read another line from target (I)
- Compare: source before target, so read another line from source (I)
- Compare: source and target keys are equal, so process the entry for I, and read another line from each (source=empty, target=J)
- As we've run out of data from source, we're done

Comment: This worked. Have implemented the algorithm. Take a look at the [Sample Code](https://gist.github.com/Gouravmoy/0fe8eea479ca8cf74de41db7c0d91f8e). Thanks a lot for such a simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Jon for the algorithm. This is my implementation of the problem. Please let me know if there are any mistakes or it can be improved.

```java
package controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadAndCompareMapOnDisk {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final String newLine = "\n";
        String sourceSortedFile = "C:\\TestData\\SourceSorted.txt";
        String targetSortedFile = "C:\\TestData\\TargetSorted.txt";
        String matchedOutputFile = "C:\\TestData\\OutputMatched.txt";
        String sourceNotPresentInTarget = "C:\\TestData\\OutputSourceUnMatched.txt";
        String targetNotPresentInSource = "C:\\TestData\\OutputTargetUnMatched.txt";
        String keyValueSeparator = "=";

        BufferedReader sourceReader;
        BufferedReader targetReader;
        BufferedWriter matchedWriter;
        BufferedWriter sourceUnMatchedWriter;
        BufferedWriter targetUnmatchedWriter;

        try {
            sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(sourceSortedFile)));
            targetReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(targetSortedFile)));

            matchedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(matchedOutputFile)));
            sourceUnMatchedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(sourceNotPresentInTarget)));
            targetUnmatchedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(targetNotPresentInSource)));
            String sourceLine = "";
            String targetLine = "";
            String sourceKey = "";
            String targetKey = "";
            String sourceValue = "";
            String targetValue = "";

            int matchedCounter = 0;
            int sourceUnMatchedCounter = 0;
            int targetUnmatchedCounter = 0;

            System.out.println("Started");
            boolean isReadSource = true;
            boolean isReadTarget = true;
            while (true) {
                if (isReadSource == true) {
                    sourceLine = sourceReader.readLine();
                }
                if (isReadTarget == true) {
                    targetLine = targetReader.readLine();
                }
                if (sourceLine == null) {
                    while (targetLine != null) {
                        targetUnmatchedWriter.write(targetLine + newLine);
                        targetLine = targetReader.readLine();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (targetLine == null) {
                    while (sourceLine != null) {
                        targetUnmatchedWriter.write(sourceLine + newLine);
                        sourceLine = sourceReader.readLine();
                    }
                    break;
                }

                sourceKey = sourceLine.split(keyValueSeparator)[0];
                targetKey = targetLine.split(keyValueSeparator)[0];
                int result = sourceKey.compareTo(targetKey);
                if (result < 0) {
                    // source before Target
                    sourceUnMatchedCounter++;
                    isReadSource = true;
                    isReadTarget = false;
                    sourceUnMatchedWriter.write(sourceLine + newLine);
                    if (sourceUnMatchedCounter % 1000 == 0) {
                        sourceUnMatchedWriter.flush();
                    }
                } else if (result > 0) {
                    // target before Source
                    targetUnmatchedCounter++;
                    isReadTarget = true;
                    isReadSource = false;
                    targetUnmatchedWriter.write(targetLine + newLine);
                    if (targetUnmatchedCounter % 1000 == 0) {
                        targetUnmatchedWriter.flush();
                    }
                } else {
                    // matched key
                    matchedCounter++;
                    sourceValue = sourceLine.split(keyValueSeparator)[1];
                    targetValue = targetLine.split(keyValueSeparator)[1];
                    matchedWriter.write("Key Matched for Matched - " + sourceKey + " and " + targetKey
                            + "Value Equals = " + (sourceValue.equals(targetValue) + "\n"));
                    if (matchedCounter % 1000 == 0) {
                        matchedWriter.flush();
                    }
                    isReadSource = true;
                    isReadTarget = true;
                }
            }
            flushAndCloseWriters(sourceReader, targetReader, matchedWriter, sourceUnMatchedWriter,
                    targetUnmatchedWriter);
            System.out.println("Finished");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void flushAndCloseWriters(BufferedReader sourceReader, BufferedReader targetReader,
            BufferedWriter matchedWriter, BufferedWriter sourceUnMatchedWriter, BufferedWriter targetUnmatchedWriter)
            throws IOException {
        targetUnmatchedWriter.flush();
        sourceUnMatchedWriter.flush();
        matchedWriter.flush();
        sourceUnMatchedWriter.close();
        targetUnmatchedWriter.close();
        matchedWriter.close();
        sourceReader.close();
        targetReader.close();
    }
}
```